# How to automatically hit "OK" box when opening a workbook from SharePoint

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

My team stores their EOM reports on SharePoint. The macro to pull all the files and compile them is complete. The only pain is that when every workbook opens there is a pop up box that says "You are opening from an untrusted source, are you sure you want to open?" I want My VBA code to automatically hit ok or ignore this so I don't have to hit OK for each team member (There are 17). I know I can add it as a trusted source, but sometimes others will need to run this report from their laptop. Suggestions?

Comment: Have your tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` ?

Comment: Be sure to set `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` at the end of your routine :)